# Suggestion applications Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof, singularity

***if $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$, then f is analytic at all points within $\gamma$***

I consider it to be false since if I consider $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$, and $\gamma:=|z|=1$, by *Cauchy's integral formula*, is satisfied
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2}dz=0$$
However $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}-\lbrace 0\rbrace$, that is, the function f is not analytic at all points of $\gamma$.

therefore the result is false.

Find a result of Morera's theorem, which adds the continuity hypothesis, on the contour, which guarantees that the previous result is true.

***Find $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{\sin{z}}{(z-\zeta)^2}dz$ where $\gamma:=|z|=1$ and $|\zeta|<1$***

By *Cauchy's integral formula* if $\zeta\in int \gamma$, it must be fulfilled that $\zeta=0$, now
$$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{\sin{z}}{(z-\zeta)^2}dz=\frac{2\pi i  f^{'}(\zeta)}{1!}=2\pi i\cos{\zeta}$$

I have a doubt regarding, if this is still fulfilled this equation for $|\zeta|>1$, I think that it is not fulfilled since the singularities of $f (z)$ would no longer be in $int\gamma$

***If $f$ is analytic within $\gamma$, except in $z_{0}$ and $(z-z_0)f(z)$ is analytic inside $\gamma$, then $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz\neq 0$***

I do not understand this last section, I must verify if it is true false, any suggestion is gratefully received.

In the same way, I would like to know if the other sections are well done, I appreciate your understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this using the Residue Theorem. The value of the integral is $2\pi i \lim (z-z_0)f(z)$. If the integral is $0$ then this limit must be $0$. Now define $g(z)=(z-z_0) f(z)$ if $z \neq z_0$ and $0$ if $z=z_0$. Then $g$ is analytic and it has a zero at $z_0$. So we can write $g(z)=(z-z_0)h(z)$ where $h$ is analytic . But this makes $f$ anayltic at $z_0$ Hence, as long as $f$ is not analytic at $z_0$ the integral cannot vanish.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not taken into account the remainder theorem, it may be that you could explain me a little better, I do not understand very well about the function $h(z)$.

Comment: @JulianBejarano If you write down the power series for $g(z)$ around the point $z_0$ the constant term is $0$. So we can factor out $z-z_0$ and what remains is a  convergent power series.  $h(z)$ is just the sum of this series.

Comment: Since it is analytic in $|z-z_0|<R$  it has power series representation, then $g(z)=(z-z_0)f(z)=(z-z_0)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-z_{0})^n$ is equal to: $a_{0}(z-z_0)+a_{1}(z-z_0)^{2}+a_{2}(z-z_0)^3+\cdots$, in this case  $h(z)$  is $f(z)$?, 
and on the other hand the statement is false?

Comment: @JulianBejarano Yes, $f=h$ so $f$ is analytic at $z_0$, but that contradicts the hypothesis.

Comment: thank very much

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy,  

Julian asked if the statement was true or false, I was a bit confused in the conclusion, you say that as long as f is not analytical in $z_0$  the integral does not disappear, therefore the exercise is true?